# How to grant Ubuntu permission for the user who login with OpenLDAP authentication?

Tags: openldap

How to grant Ubuntu permission for the user who login with OpenLDAP authentication?
For example, to have the user only can access some folders or run some kind of commands or only can use Firefox web browser.